# Do I need to restart NginX after reconfigure for passenger to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I just updated my NginX configuration.
In the config I've added a new server with a different environment for a rails application.

I've reloaded the configuration (`sbin/nginx -s reload`) and deployed the application to the right folder but nothing seems to happen, NginX throws 404 not found..

Is there anything more I need to do?

Do I need to restart NginX or passenger for example?

Comment: Why is this a Ruby or Rails question?

Comment: He's clearly using nginx to serve a rails app via passenger, and maybe he wasn't sure if that detail was relevant or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you don't need to restart.

Passenger isn't able to restart (as far as I've found out) and NginX only needs a reload.